# OAuth 2.0 With Desktop App. No Microsoft login screen opened

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, oauth

I tried to call a test connection using C#. At the beginning it worked, a few days later, I have deleted the token and tried again => the user authentication / Microsoft login window does not open anymore.
*No matter if the settings were wrong or right, the window always opened.*

(it did not work even on a completely rebuilt PC)

**Problem:**
When executing the method "await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();" It looks like the app is waiting for input in the microsoft login window, but no window opens. Unfortunately there is no response.

**My Azure App Configuration:**

I registered my app in the Azure portal as "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft account".

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99iKe.png)

**RedirectUri**
For.NET Desktop i used: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyIIQ.png)

In the API permissions i added following permission scopes:

- offline_access
- email
- IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
- POP.AccessAsUser.All
- SMTP.Send

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7TNU.png)

In the line `var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();` it should open the window.

**My C# Code:**

```
            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
               .Create(accessParameters.ClientId)
               .WithAuthority(
                   AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdAndPersonalMicrosoftAccount
                   )
               .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
               .Build();
 
            TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(app.UserTokenCache);

            var scopes = new string[]
            {
                "offline_access",
                "email",
                "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All",
                "https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All",
                "https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send",
            };

            string userName;
            string accessToken;

            var account = (await app.GetAccountsAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                AuthenticationResult refresh = await app
                    .AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                userName = refresh.Account.Username;
                accessToken = refresh.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException e)
            {
                var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                userName = result.Account.Username;
                accessToken = result.AccessToken;
            }

            string[] acc = { userName, accessToken };
            return acc;
```

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgDPX.png)

Comment: The token is a cookie and when you do not see a login the cookie is being used.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I edited the post. I have of course deleted the token before.

Comment: What do you mean by "Its Loading"? Do you get any response?  What is status in the response.  I can't tell if the connection is completing.  We need to determine if the connection is completing (or not completing), the authentication is working (or failing), or the processing of the request is failing. what sometimes happens is you successfully create a cookie using another application.  Then run c# using existing cookie and code works.  When you delete the cookie you think the authentication was working, but it was really done with anther app.

Comment: When executing the method "await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();" It looks like the app is waiting for input in the microsoft login window, but no window opens. Unfortunately there is no response.

Comment: The server may think you are a hacker and simply not responding either because you tried too many times or the format of the request is not correct.  I tried you link to Microsoft and not getting a response.  I do not think you have a "nativeclient".  I suspect the Microsoft code is old. Always check the date of sample code to make sure it is recent. Try following code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/shopping-content/code-example-authentication-oauth?force_isolation=true